# How to make Java server read from variable instead of console input?

Tags: java, sockets, server

I am creating a simple socket program that can read user input and store it in its variable. it also allows to send messages to the server.

The client enters their details (name etc) then enters connection details. I have created methods to send these variables but they do not work correctly.

Expected result from below: Store `playerName` from client class to `playerName` in server class.
Actual Result: first input after connection is stored into the server's `playerName` Variable

//Server client Class

```
public static String playerName = "Client";


public static void playerDetails() {
        Scanner playerInfo = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome! Please Enter Your Player Name:");
        playerName = playerInfo.nextLine();
}

public void sendNameToServer(String pName) throws IOException {
        if (this.clientSocket == null || this.output == null)
            throw new SocketException("Socket does not exist");
        this.output.writeObject(playerName);
    }

    public void sendMessageToServer(String msg) throws IOException {
        if (this.clientSocket == null || this.output == null)
            throw new SocketException("socket does not exist");

        this.output.writeObject(msg);
    }


public void runClient() {
        try {
            BufferedReader fromConsole = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String message = null;

            while (true) {
                message = fromConsole.readLine();
                handleUserInput(message);
                if(message.equals("over"))

                    break;
            }



// server client Manager Class

try {
                this.out = new ObjectOutputStream(this.clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                this.in = new ObjectInputStream(this.clientSocket.getInputStream());            
            }



            String pName = null;
            String msg = "";

            //Name

            pName = (String)this.in.readObject();
            this.server.sendNameToServer(pName, this);



            msg = (String)this.in.readObject();
            this.server.handleMessagesFromClient(msg, this);


//Abstract Methods
public abstract class ServerAbstractComponents {
    public abstract void handleMessagesFromClient(String msg, ServerClientManager clientmgr);
    public abstract void sendMessageToClient(String msg, ServerClientManager clientmgr);
    public abstract void sendNameToServer(String pName, ServerClientManager clientmgr);

//Server Class
public  String playerName;
        public synchronized void sendNameToServer(String pName, ServerClientManager client) {
            playerName = pName;
            }


public synchronized void handleMessagesFromClient(String msg, ServerClientManager client) {

            // format the client message before displaying in server's terminal output. 
             String formattedMessage = String.format("[client %d] : %s", client.getClientID(), msg); 

                if(msg.equals(new String("test"))) {
                    System.out.println("your name is:" + playerName);
                } else 

            display(formattedMessage);
}
```

[image: Client]

[image: Server]

Comment: You have posted too much code to wade through - see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly. However, my *guess* is that the problem is `playerName` is `static`. Try removing the `static` keyword from `playerName` (both method and variable).

Comment: Hello, I have tried removing the static keyword but I am having trouble instantiating the class, I have tried to create an instance of the class to make the programme run.
```ServerClient myClient = new ServerClient();
  myClient.playerDetails();  ```
however i now cannot make a refference to the non static method in the main

Comment: I didn't see any instance of ServerSocket or Socket used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I have done it.

```
//Writes player Name as an object to the output Stream
        System.out.println("Welcome, Enter your name :");
        try {
            Scanner playerInfo = new Scanner(System.in);
            playerName2 = playerInfo.nextLine();
            this.output.writeObject(playerName2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } System.out.println("Welcome to The Game! " + playerName2);
```

//ServerClientManager Class

```
            //Name2
            try {
            pName2 = (String)this.in.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.server.sendNameToServer2(pName2, this);
```

//Abstract Class

```
public abstract void sendNameToServer(String pName2, ServerClientManager clientmgr);
```

//Server Class

```
public String playerName2;
        public synchronized void sendNameToServer2(String pName2, ServerClientManager client) {
            client.playerName2 = pName2;
        }
```